# Jquery ready function conventions

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive

what is the difference b/w

```
$(function(){

});
```

and

```
(function ($) {
//found this code in jquery uobtrusive ajax
}(JQuery));
```

first code snippet is simply shorthand for document ready. i have no idea about second code snippet: what does it do and how does it differ from the first code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second snippet creates an anonymous function and executes it immediately, without waiting for anything to load.

It's used to create a *local* variable (parameter) named `$` that refers to `jQuery`, even if someone calls `jQuery.noConflict()`.

It also hides internal variables created in the function from the global scope.

Comment: how can i change values of some variables inside this anonymous function plz see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135029/context-is-missing-when-using-unobtrusive-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc-3