# Stop unobstrusive validate from triggering for specific submit buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have several `input` fields of type `submit` on my page. For some of these I want validation to occur as normal but on others I do not. Each `submit` button posts the form back to the controller, setting a command value for each button. This allows the action to perform the relevant function. However, if I add the class `cancel` to the relevant `input` tag, validation doesn't occur for them. But then I don't get a value for the command posted back to the controller action. So I can either not validate or get a command value but not both.

To set up;

Models;

```
public void SubData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public void SomeViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<SubData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

In HTML;

```
<input type="submit" name="command" value="AddData" />
<input type="submit" name="command" value="DeleteData/>
<input type="submit" name="command" value="SaveAll/>
```

Controller;

```
public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel model, string command)
{
    switch (command)
    {
        case "AddData":
            model.Stuff.Add(new SubData());
            break;
        case "DeleteData":
            // you get the idea...
            break;
    }
}
```

Javascript (taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17401660);

```
$(function () {
    // allow delete actions to trigger a submit without activating validation
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit].cancel', function (evt) {
        // find parent form, cancel validation and submit it
        // cancelSubmit just prevents jQuery validation from kicking in
        $(this).closest('form').validate().cancelSubmit = true;
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

So, if I have `<input type="submit" class="cancel" value="AddSomething" />` then validation doesn't occur (yay!) but I get no value supplied in the action's parameter `command` (boo!). Taking out `cancel` triggers validation and I get a value for `command` once validation is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `evt.preventDefault()` to prevent the subimition of this input

```
$(function () {
    // allow delete actions to trigger a submit without activating validation
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit].cancel', function (evt) {
        //use  the preventDefault() to stop any submition from here
        evt.preventDefault();
        // find parent form, cancel validation and submit it
        // cancelSubmit just prevents jQuery validation from kicking in
        $(this).closest('form').validate().cancelSubmit = true;
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The issue isn't that I can't turn off validation on the input, it's that doing so stops the `input`'s value from posting to the controller action